# Communicate to a Windows Service in a server from console app in clients

Tags: c#

I have a C# console app that will be installed in about **500** users pc's that **won't have access to internet**. This console app will be executed by other application after a specific task is completed.

On the other hand I will create a Windows Service (don't know if this is correct or I should host a server in this windows service) installed on the main server that will have internet access.

The idea is that all the console apps send information (such as machine name, user, ip address, etc.) to the Windows Service on server and then the server will push that information to a web service located on the internet.

I don't know if having a self-hosted C# server on the server is the right way to go, or maybe there is a simple way to do this.

This is a code that found for self-hosted WCF that could be an option:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace SelfHost
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string name);
    }

    public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
    {
        public string SayHello(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hello");

            // Create the ServiceHost.
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
            {
                // Enable metadata publishing.
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
                // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
                // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
                // by the service.
                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Close the ServiceHost.
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Computers would need internet access to send information to a WCF service. Are they all on a shared intranet that this service would be placed on?

Comment: The self-hosted service will be running just on the serve with internet, the other pc's just have access to the local LAN so they can call the WCF service on the local network. Then server can send information outside

Comment: That sounds alright to me.. Why do you want to host it in Windows Service, but not in IIS?

Comment: @SateeshPagolu the server won't have IIS enabled.